# Zuul with web socket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-websocket, netflix-zuul

We currently have a direct Websocket connection that goes to a backend webservice
from our UI Application. Now when we are trying  to do the same through Zuul(ApiGateway) we are not able to connect to backend service 
We have gone through below issue that does not solve our problem https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/163

but it gives me an alternative in below link
https://jmnarloch.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/spring-cloud-sock-js-stomp-zuul-no-websockets/
I am considering it as a last solution.

My other Question is, if we want to use websocket protocol with zuul what changes we need to perform in zuul as I am new to websocket because we know spring support websocket and Zuul is a spring based service (Correct if I am wrong)

**UPDATE**

This feature wont be available with zuul 2 as of my knowledge.  Zuul 2 will not be incorporated into Spring Cloud. See spring cloud gateway for websockets support. check this out(https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/163)

Comment: you can look [here](https://github.com/bilak/spring-websocket-rabbitmq-poc) I've configured websocket with zuul through stomp/sockjs protocol. Take a look mainly at gateway and websocket1 applications

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will look into it. :)

Comment: You can use Spring Cloud Gateway.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_websocket_routing_filter

Answer (score 2):

Zuul 1 is unable to support websockets. Zuul 2 will support it https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/112.

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, Thanks for your reply

We have used zuul-core version:2.0.0-r.c.2 which is present in "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.zuul/zuul-core" but it is not working for us and there is no release for spring-cloud-starter-zuul for zuul 2 and i am not able to get any roadmap for it and websocket is must for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: We won't move to zuul 2 until it is Generally Available, not a pre-release RC2. We could start integration work soon. We have an open issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/163

Comment: hi @spencergibb, Thanks again
we will wait for zuul 2 and will try some work arounds 
I am facing one more problem with zuul. It is modifying my content type(multipart form-data to text/plain ) header and I am using 1.1.6.Release i know it is fix 1.1.0.M5 but I am still facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

We have created a zuul proxy web socket support feature to resolve this issue. I will be creating a pull request in spring cloud netflix soon. The library and demo are currently hosted in github.

Comment: /@mthizo247 No Link

Comment: @Diyoda_ this one - https://github.com/mthizo247/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-websocket

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` instead of `zuul`. WebSocket is supported and it's a much better developer experience since it's tightly integrated with Spring.

Comment: Thanks @panduka, but now we are not depending on spring for routing request and service discovery. Still thanks for update