# Use Web-sockets with Zuul and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, netflix-zuul

I am trying to find out a solution in which i can open a web socket on UI and send it to zuul Gateway and same socket should route to micro service. i am using below dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please let me know if anyone came across the same situation or have any pointers on same.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:

Get to know that zuul 2 do have a support for web sockets but does not have integration with spring. so i have used spring-cloud-gateway to achieve the same scenario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472635/zuul-with-web-socket

Comment: @pvkiran - thanks, but i already checked it , it just mentioned that Juul 2 will support it. Doesn't provide any implementation details ..